# How can I get a const to load after my map function has finished?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, plugins, attributes

I've been working on this for the last few days. It took me a while to figure out that my const is loading before my map function finishes loading.

Here is my const and map function in my edit.js file

```
    const blockProps = useBlockProps();
    const { backgroundColor, textColor, selectedValue, myNumber, menuItems } = attributes;
    const updateAttributes = (src, heading, para, href, index) => {
        const theAttributeUpdate = [...menuItems];
        theAttributeUpdate[index] = { image: src, header: heading, excerpt: para, link: href };
        setAttributes({menuItems: theAttributeUpdate})
    }

...

            {newArray.filter((m, idx) => m.catagory == selectedValue).map((m) => {

                    return (
                        <div class="blog-stamp">
                            <img class="stamp-image" src={m.image} width="200" height="200" />
                            <RichText
                                tagName="h3"
                                class="stamp-title"
                                onChange={(heading) => updateAttributes(src, heading, para, href, index)}
                                value={m.label}
                            />
                            <RichText
                                tagName="p"
                                class="stamp-excerpt"
                                onChange={(para) => updateAttributes(src, heading, para, href, index)}
                                value={m.content}
                            />
                            <p class="button-parent">
                                <a
                                    href={m.link}
                                    className="sfs-button"
                                    style={{ backgroundColor: backgroundColor, color: textColor }}
                                >
                                    {'Read more'}
                                </a>
                            </p>
                        </div>)
                })}
```

Here are the attributes in block.json

```
        "menuItems": {
            "type": "array",
            "source": "query",
            "selector": "div",
            "default": [],
            "query": {
                "image": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "source": "attribute",
                    "selector": ".stamp-image",
                    "attribute": "src"
                },
                "header": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "selector": "h3",
                    "source": "html"
                },
                "excerpt": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "selector": "p",
                    "source": "html"
                },
                "link": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "source": "attribute",
                    "selector": ".button-parent a",
                    "attribute": "href"
                }
            }
        },
```

The const is placed above my return statement. I believe if I can get it to load after my map function it will save an array of attributes so I can use them in my save.js file.

I am a newbie. So, any help is greatly appriciated.

Comment: It's difficult to work out what the problem is - you have many `const`s in that code. To which are you referring, and could you go into a little more detail as to what you're expecting to happen.

Comment: One problem is that you're not passing `index` to updateAttributes.

Comment: @Andy - This is the code I am refering to ```   const updateAttributes = (src, heading, para, href, index) => {
        const theAttributeUpdate = [...menuItems];
        theAttributeUpdate[index] = { image: src, header: heading, excerpt: para, link: href };
        setAttributes({menuItems: theAttributeUpdate})
    }```

Comment: @James - I've include index. Am I missing something? Please give an example